# How i can export event changer for es6?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I have function for optimize window resize.

```
(function() {
    var throttle = function(type, name, obj) {
        obj = obj || window;
        var running = false;
        var func = function() {
            if (running) { return; }
            running = true;
             requestAnimationFrame(function() {
                obj.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(name));
                running = false;
            });
        };
        obj.addEventListener(type, func);
    };

    /* init - you can init any event */
    throttle("resize", "optimizedResize");
})();

// handle event
window.addEventListener("optimizedResize", function() {
    console.log("Resource conscious resize callback!");
});
```

But now i start project in es6, and i have no idia, how to use it in import export for using it in addevent listener on athother js files?

I want to do import this function and using it in another constructors and files, but i dont know how:

```
window.addEventListener("optimizedResize", function() {
    console.log("Resource conscious resize callback!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe there is more great way for import/export but just for info. you can create an object. like

```
var obj = {
    myCustomEvent: function(eventType) {
       window.addEventListener(eventType, function() {
           console.log("Resource conscious resize callback!");
      });
   }
}
export {obj};

// Usage
import {obj} from '...';

obj.myCustomEvent('event_name');
```